# Nancy web framework for Java

Tags: java, nancy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple Java web framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125529/simple-java-web-framework)

I went to the alt.net catchup in Melbourne last night and there was a demo of the [Nancy web framework](http://elegantcode.com/2010/11/28/introducing-nancy-a-lightweight-web-framework-inspired-by-sinatra/)

Is there a similar micro framework in Java?

Comment: Thanks Greg Ill check that out it looks the same

Comment: Play (mentioned in the link) is not particularly lightweight. Something that runs on a JVM, also based on Sinatra, is Scalatra. You would have to write a little bit of code in Scala, but it can call your Java objects.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, I had a flick through the other post and yeah seems like there isn't really anything as easy to get set up and going as Nancy.. its a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried these, but possibilities include (at least if you mean the Jave the platform, not just the language):

- [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/) - Micro web framework in Java
- [Scalatra](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra) - Micro web framework in Scala
- [RatPack](https://github.com/bleedingwolf/Ratpack) - Micro web framework in Groovy